# How can I add a separator to the Place sidebar in nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, places

I'd like to drag a few more folders to the places sidebar in nautilus, but want to group these new ones separately to the default folders (like Dropbox, Downloads and Documents). Is there a way to add a new separator to the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not ideal but as far as I can see the only option you have short of [filing a bug and chasing it through](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/bugtrackers/gnome-bugs) or writing and applying a patch.

- Open Nautilus
- Browse to a directory that you don't want to bookmark, for example /bin
- From the Bookmarks menu click on "Add Bookmark"
- Then Right click on the bookmark for /bin and choose "Rename..."
- Rename the bookmark to "----------"
- Close Nautilus and open it again
- you now have something that looks vaguely but not very much like a separator.

EDIT: Looks like there is [already a bug filed for this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/260857). [Add your own point of view here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/260857).

Answer (score 5):

Hack on the code.

AFAIK there's no gconf (or other) way to alter the places that aren't bookmarks.

Comment: Hack the world ;)